# duplicates outcomes using "group by"

Tags: mysql

I have a problem with this query

```
select alarmas, count(alarmas) 
from lista_equipos 
where alarmas not like'%n/a%' 
group by alarmas;
```

the result don't consolidate the major alarm count.

```
Critical    6
Major       1
Major       9
```

Warning 36
[image]
[image]

Comment: Probably spaces at the end `select TRIM(alarmas), count(alarmas) from lista_equipos where alarmas not like'%n/a%' group by TRIM(alarmas)` Am I right?

Comment: let me i try, but i checked and its the same word Major..

Comment: didn't work, its the same result. Thx

Comment: `SELECT *, LENGTH(alarmas) from lista_equipos where alarmas not like'%n/a%'` Please share result

Comment: hi the result http://i.stack.imgur.com/7fxXi.png.

Comment: `SELECT *, LENGTH(alarmas) from lista_equipos where alarmas like '%Major%'`

Comment: Hi the result is: http://i.stack.imgur.com/6vTYv.png

Comment: 6 vs 5 I was right You have some character maybe new line feed. Check for `lagasca1`

Comment: `SELECT alarmas, HEX(alarmas) from lista_equipos where alarmas like '%Major%'` will show what the extra non-printable character is.

Comment: it returned only 9 rows using 'SELECT *, LENGTH(alarmas) from lista_equipos where alarmas like 'Major';'

Comment: `SELECT alarmas, HEX(alarmas) from lista_equipos where alarmas like '%Major%' AND nombre = 'lagasca1'`

Comment: but isn't a space... I'm not sure whats hapen

Comment: Linefeed, null character, any unicode. There are thousands of non-printable spaces/control chars. Copy the value and paste to question, but as text not as image. And I will tell you what character it is.

Comment: i find the problem, check this.

Comment: '1685', 'lagasca1', 'TiMOS-B-6.2.R1 ', '172.22.217.80', 'ANSI', '7705-SAR8', 'Major\r', '50', '6'
'1246', 'queguayacan1', 'TiMOS-B-6.2.R1 ', '172.22.180.6', 'ANSI', '7705-SAR8', 'Major', '83', '5'

Comment: this "\r " is the cause

Comment: **`select  REPLACE(alarmas, '\r',''), count(alarmas) 
from lista_equipos 
where alarmas not like'%n/a%' 
group by REPLACE(alarmas, '\r','');`**

Comment: i don't know how ignore this simbol...

Comment: thats a really good idea i need to implement in the accquisition code in all the columns.    : )   THX.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is `\r` character. Quickfix:

```
SELECT REPLACE(alarmas, '\r','') AS alarmas, COUNT(alarmas) 
FROM lista_equipos 
WHERE alarmas NOT LIKE '%n/a%' 
GROUP BY REPLACE(alarmas, '\r','');
```

The correct way is to clean data before insert.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why we need to use like operator here. Below query should work:

```
select alarmas, count(*)
from lista_equipos
where alarmas not like '%N/A%'
group by alarmas
```

Alternatively, if we want to ignore spaces and case (as we seem to have values with spaces around them) then, we can use the below query:

```
select lower(trim(alarmas)) as alarm, count(*)
from lista_equipos
where alarmas not like '%N/A%'
group by alarm
```

Comment: Critical 6
Major
 1
Major 9
N/A
 3
N/A 980
Warning 36

Comment: i used the like operator because I'm not interested in see the N/A.

Comment: I have modified the query to exclude N/A.

Comment: I have also added alternative query if that helps.